# Converting slope map in degrees to radians in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, dem, spatial-analyst

I have to make a sediment transport index (STI) map but I get empty cells in the output.

In reply to similar question in this site, it was mentioned that the slope map should be converted from degrees to radians.

Can anyone please tell me how to convert the slope map from degree to radian? Or you can simply tell me the procedure to get a sediment transport index map (STI) map without empty cells.

Comment: Which "similar question" was that?  Please always include links so that potential answerers do not have to spend their volunteered time looking for questions that may be relevant to your question.

Answer (score 3):

There is a tool "Angle Conversion" in the ArcGIS [Geomorphometry & Gradient Metrics toolbox](http://evansmurphy.wixsite.com/evansspatial/arcgis-gradient-metrics-toolbox) for conversion between degrees and radians. However, the conversion is quite simple using raster calculator. For degrees to radians the formula is: [degree * pi / 180]. In the raster calculator you could use: `Float('slope' * 3.141593 / 180)`

There is also the DEG constant ~57.296 (180/pi) which can be used to convert degrees to radians by simply dividing. `Float('slope' / deg)`

Comment: Thank you..i ll definitely follow this and reply if it works..